# Initializing with a subclass's ctor

Tags: c++, oop

```
struct A {
    B b;
    A(int x):b(x){}
    A(int x, float g) // how to implement this? I want to init b as a C. 
};
struct B {
    enum {e_c, e_d} type;
    int i;
    B(int i_):i(i_){}
};
struct C : public B {
    float f;
    C(int i_, float f_):B(i),f(f_){}
};
struct D : public B {
    double ff;
    D(int i_, double d):B(i),ff(d){}
};
```

Perhaps there is another way to code this? Originally I just had the class B, but I decided to split it up so I didn't keep adding (incompatible/mutually exclusive) fields to B. My solution was, when A uses b it checks b's enum to see what type it is, then casts a B* to a C* or a D* to get the float or double. My problem is now I don't know how to let A initialize b. Does the language even let me do something like that?

**edit**: I just realized A's b couldn't possibly have allocated space to allow for C or D's extra fields. There wouldn't be any available space to store the float or double. So I guess the right way to do what i want is to add into B a `union {float f; double ff;};`?

Comment: You cannot "init `b` as `C`", since you have an actual object member of type `B`! You **could** make the object a `B*`, but why not make the member of type `C` directly?

Comment: Anyway, having an enum in the base class to enumerate possible derived classes smells like an upcoming design car crash. If you post your actual problem, we can think about a better solution.

Comment: I guess another way to phrase my question is: is there a more OOP way to do a union? I just know that if I use a union, say like in this example it has a float and a double in it, and I interpret a double-value as a float-value, I'm going to get garbage, and that could make nasty bugs.

Comment: No no, say what problem you really want to solve. Let's not think about unions. I'm betting that there'll be some polymorphism and virtual functions in the final answer.

Comment: That sounds about right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is a bit confused.  But maybe you want a pointer?

```
struct A {
    B *b;
    A(int x):b(new B(x)) {}
    A(int x, float g):b(new C(x,g)) {}
   ~A() { delete b; }  // Very important!
};
```

Note that if you do this, `B` **must** have a virtual destructor.  You will also need to think about what it means to copy an `A` object.

Comment: **Must** mention to give `B` virtual destructor! :-) And make `A` uncopyable while you're at it. Also, the OP's idea to put an enum into `B` makes it look like an upcoming bad design choice...

Comment: @Kerrek: Ah, good point, didn't spot that the virtual dtor was missing from the OP's code.  Copy construction/assignment could easily lead down a garden-path of tangentials, but I'll mention that too.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit is correct.

Probably the normal way to do what you want is to store the `B` by (preferably smart) pointer and allocate the proper type in the respective constructor.